# Service throws an error 'get is not a function'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are tons of similar question here on stack, but I can't find something that could help me. May be I am blind.

I have a service, which sends request to server.

```
app.factory(
    "myService",
    [
        "$http", "config",
        function ($http, config)
        {
            return {
                get: function (query)
                {
                    return $http.get(
                        config.apiUri + "path/getSomething",
                        {
                            params: query
                        });
                }
            };
        }
    ])
```

And how I call it:

```
myService
.get($scope.query)
.then(
     function (result)
     {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        $scope.entries = result.data;
     });
```

I don't understand where is I made a mistake. Help me, please. It actually worked, but now it isn't.

Comment: what's `myservice` in your code?

Comment: add the code where you inject the service

Comment: [Its seems to be working fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/0hLrcqop/)

Comment: @Karim thank u for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

I am really blind.

In injection there was a wrong order of my intities.

```
"$scope", "$routeParams", "$window", "myService",
function ($scope, $routeParams, myService, $window) { ... }
```

Instead of

```
"$scope", "$routeParams", "$window", "myService",
function ($scope, $routeParams, $window, myService,) { ... }
```

Thanks everyone.